# Setting breakpoints for Window object in browser (chrome)

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I have a web page which i don't own so not aware of the code.

Now i have a cross button clicking on which is actually closing the web page. 
But its not calling window.close directly. Now i want to put breakpoint in

> window.close

such that i can capture the stack.

Is it possible to put breakpoint in java script code of HTML's DOM like

> window.close

?
I am using Chrome. I do see DOM breakpoints, is it the same thing which i am talking about ?
cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Can you share the link of the website on which you are trying this.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on the click event.